# Android AsyncTask and JNI native code

Tags: android-asynctask, java-native-interface

I am playing with AsyncTask class in order to do some time-consuming background processing. I extended the AsyncTask class with my own implementation. When the `doInBackground()` method is called, it will call a native C function (this function will do some dummy time-consuming processing and returns a string). This function will run say for 10 seconds. To facilitate debug, every tot amount of work the native function will use the LOGI() macro to output a message on the Eclipse console. If the user press a button before the native method has finished its computation, i call the AsyncTask  method `cancel(true)`, but the native function runs till the end. I think that the reason is because the native function resides on another process (the process relative to the shared library loaded by my Activity). The first question is: what will happen when the return statement of the native method will be executed? To whom will be the string returned? The second question is about how to stop the native function safely (it allocates memory, so i want to stop its excecution and free the used memory).